# Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. Wanted but not invoked

Tags: session, junit, mocking

My java code:

```
@Override
public void initConnection(WebSocketSession session) {
    JSch jSch = new JSch();
    SshConnectInfo sshConnectInfo = new SshConnectInfo();
    sshConnectInfo.setJSch(jSch);
    sshConnectInfo.setWebSocketSession(session);
    String uuid = String.valueOf(session.getAttributes().get(ConstantPool.USER_UUID_KEY));
    sshMap.put(uuid, sshConnectInfo);
}
```

My test class:

```
public class WebSshServiceImplTest {
private WebSshServiceImpl webSshService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception 
{ 
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
this.webSshService = new WebSshServiceImpl(20);
}
@Mock
ConcurrentMap<String, Object> sshMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Test
public void initConnectionSuccess() throws Exception{
    WebSocketSession session = mock(WebSocketSession.class);
    session.getAttributes().put(ConstantPool.USER_UUID_KEY,"asdfgh");
    SshConnectInfo sshConnectInfo = new SshConnectInfo();
    doReturn(sshConnectInfo).when(sshMap).put("asdfgh",sshConnectInfo);
    webSshService.initConnection(session);
   verify(sshMap,times(1)).put("asdfgh",sshConnectInfo);
}
```

When I run this test case it is failing due to below error

```
Wanted but not invoked:
sshMap.put(
    "asdfgh",
    SshConnectInfo(webSocketSession=null, jSch=null, channel=null)
);
-> at com.extremecloudiq.websshserver.service.WebSshServiceImplTest.initConnectionSuccess(WebSshServiceImplTest.java:48)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Can someone please help me on this?I tried Autowiring the serviceimpl but it was throwing null pointer exception. Not sure what to change in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not injecting the mock at all, have you tried adding the annotation `@InjectMocks` to the `WebSshServiceImpl`?

Keep in mind that `@InjectMocks` annotation allows to inject into the underlying object the different mocks created by `@Mock`.

```
@InjectMocks
private WebSshServiceImpl webSshService;
```

Comment: I tried this since I don't have default constructor in WebSshServiceImpl getting this error.
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'webSshService'! Cause: the type 'WebSshServiceImpl' has no default constructor
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.